# Xamarin - APK installs but stops working

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I am new to `Xamarin`.

I created a fresh project using `xamarin studio`. I made no changes, built it and the building was successful but when i installed the app on an android device it installs but **stops working**.

error message :-

> "APP has stopped working "

Comment: Are you side-loading the app? If so, click `Build` in the Output window dropdown instead of `Debug` and see if there are  more helpful error message there

Comment: i built it then i deployed to device which is an android emulator (Blue stacks ). It gave this warning    C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2,2): Warning: No -tsa or -tsacert is provided and this jar is not timestamped. Without a timestamp, users may not be able to validate this jar after the signer certificate's expiration date (2046-06-07) or after any future revocation date. (SampleApp1.Droid). It showed deployment completed but the same thing happens again. The app opens up and closes immediately.

Comment: That is a normal warning for side-load builds and it can be ignored. Try uninstalling the app from the emulator, completely deleting each project's `/bin/` and `/obj/` folders, rebuild the solution, and deploy it again